# Replace words within a string in python

Tags: python

I am a very beginning programmer looking for some help with what is probably a very simple problem. I am trying to write a program that will read a .txt file and then replace any words with an 'e' in them with 'xxxxx'.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def replace_ewords(text):
    ntext = text.replace('e', 'xxxxx')

def main():
    filename = "gb.txt"
    text = readfile(filename)
    new_text = replace_ewords(text)
    print(new_text)

main()
```

Could someone help me with this any give me any critques/pointers?

Comment: First your function `replace_ewords` needs to `return ntext`.

Comment: What is the function "readfile()" doing?.....I believe that replace_ewords() function must be place in a function that loops over each in line in the file object...can you provide more codes?

Comment: Are you trying to replace all the words that contain an 'e' with 'xxxxx'? Or are you just replacing the 'e' in each word with 'xxxxx'?

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace_ewords(text):
    words = []
    text = text.split(' ')
    for word in text:
        if "e" in text:
            words.append("x"*len(text))
        else:
            words.append(text)
    return " ".join(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('filename') as f:   # Better way to open files :)
    line_list = []
    for line in file:   # iterate line by line
        word_list = []
        for word in line.split()   # split each line into words
            if 'e' in word:
                word = 'xxxxx'     # replace content if word has 'e'
            word_list.append(word) # create new list for the word content in new file
        line_list.append(' '.join(word_list))   # list of modified line

# write this content to the file
```

One line for the loops can be written in the form of list comprehension as:

```
 [' '.join([('xxxx' if 'e' in word else word) for word in line]) for line in file.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

one liner:

```
print "\n".join([" ".join([[word, "xxx"]["e" in word] for word in line.split()]) for line in open("file").readlines()])
```